# How to get value from outside of the function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I get a var value from another function?

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function GetBiggestValue() {
        var value = 0;
        $('#tagCloud li a').each(function() {
            if (value < $(this).attr('value')) {
                value = $(this).attr('value');
            }
        });
        var FullValue = value;
    }

    function Abc(){
        console.log(FullValue);
    }

    Abc();
});
```

**HTML:**

```html
<ul id="tagCloud">
    <li><a href="#" value="1">Val 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" value="2">Val 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" value="3">Val 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" value="4">Val 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access variables from other contexts than your own or one of the parent contexts. The `FullValue` variable is private to the `GetBiggestValue()` function because you used the `var` statement to define the variable. The correct procedure in your case would be to return `value` from the `GetBiggestValue()` function (although one might come up with another solution using a variable outside `GetBiggestValue()` to store the value).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function GetBiggestValue() {
        var value = 0;
        $('#tagCloud li a').each(function() {
            if (value < $(this).attr('value')) {
                value = $(this).attr('value');
            }
        });
        return value;
    }

    function Abc(){
        console.log(GetBiggestValue());
    }
    Abc();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you want to use this value anywhere. So call GetBiggestValue() function and assign it a variable.

```
function GetBiggestValue() {
    var value = 0;
    $('#tagCloud li a').each(function() {
        if (value < $(this).attr('value')) {
            value = $(this).attr('value');
        }
    });
    return value;
}

var FullValue = GetBiggestValue();

function Abc(){
    console.log(FullValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just return the value from the GetBiggestValue function:

```
function GetBiggestValue() {
    var value = 0;
    $('#tagCloud li a').each(function() {
        if (value < $(this).attr('value')) {
            value = $(this).attr('value');
        }
    });
    return value;
}

function Abc(){
    console.log(GetBiggestValue());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

declare outside the function

```
var value = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
function GetBiggestValue() {
        value = 0;
        $('#tagCloud li a').each(function() {
            if (value < $(this).attr('value')) {
                value = $(this).attr('value');
            }
        });

    }
    function Abc(){
        console.log(value);
    }
    Abc();
});
```

or return value

Comment: Sorry... That doesn't work because `FullValue` is still private to the `GetBiggestValue()` context.

Comment: Correct approach, wrong implementation. I'll undo downvote after you fix it. :)

Comment: Above code decalres value as global. If u want FullValue to be accessible, move declaration outside the jQuery code

Comment: The approach is indeed valid, but your implementation is still wrong. `Abc()` tries to access `FullValue` which is not available in the `Abc()`-context (`value` would be available though).